# how wait for threads to write the result to an output file?

Tags: python

I'm currently instantiating some threads to read some files as below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had an Array of Threads then after starting all of them you could loop through and call `join` for each

```
for (int i = 0; i < ; i++) {
      threadArray[i].join();
}
```

You will need to change your code to

```
for (int i = 0; i < SEARCH_THREADS; i++) {
      Thread t = new Thread(new StringSearcher(queue, keyword));
      arrayThread[i] = t;
      t.start();
}
```